# Add virtual directory to an existing WebSite

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, virtual-directory, azureportal, azure-appservice

Is it possible to add a [virtual directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory) (like in IIS) to an existing website, hosted in [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview). If so can this be done via the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[**Virtual Directories**](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory) are *supported* for **Azure Websites**. See [Configuring Azure Websites](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/) for what you can do through the [Azure Management Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/).

From the Azure Portal:

1. Click on the **Website** and go to **Configure**.
2. Then scroll down to **virtual applications and directories** (*the last config section*).
3. Enter your virtual directory and the physical path relative to the site root and click **Save**.

[image: Entering virtual directory and the physical path]

As an alternative to **Azure Websites**, you could use the [Cloud Services Web Role](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/cloud-services/) or [Virtual Machine](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/) capability. You could also use [Azure Storage](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/data-management/) to link to your static content.

Comment: Not sure this is still applicable. If you actually configure the site on Azure, you can set virtual directories under the Configure tab of the site.

Comment: @LookitsPuck - you are correct. I don't see an official announcement from MS on it, but there is [documentation regarding **virtual applications and directories** for websites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/). I also see the option to create **virtual directories** or **applications** under Configuration for websites now.

Comment: Indded, virtual directories are now available for Azure Websites.