# Deploying two web projects (one mvc, one webapi) to one Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

In my solution, I have one MVC app which I'll host on www.domain.com
I also have one Web API project, which will be hosted on api.domain.com

Is it possible to deploy these to one (for penny-pinching reasons) App Service, or are they (and should be) separate?

Comment: I think virtual directory is what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115290/add-virtual-directory-to-existing-website-on-azure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Azure App Service (except the free and shared tiers), you don't pay per app but per server in a App Service Plan.
Thanks to that, you can for example deploy 42 apps in the same App Service Plan for the same price than 1 app.

App Service pricing page can be found at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/

I hope this helps.
Regards,