# Azure Web App - Multiple apps hosting

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In my local IIS server, i have created a IIS website and  deployed  3 ASP.NET web application such that they will have URL like
IIS URL/webapp1 , IIS URL/webapp2 , IIS URL/webapp3 and it works like charm. I am able to deploy only one web application in Azure webapp and not others.

Can i deploy more than one web application in one Azure web app ? If yes, then how ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5):

My solution is described below. First create a sample AzureWebsite -

[image]

Setup up an additional application in the AzureWebsite as follows. Navigate to `Configuration tab` and create an application as shown below –
[image]

By creating above application we reserved `/` to MVC site and then `/webapi` to webapi endpoints.

Lets say you want to publish MVC and Web API projects from VS Solution as shown below.

[image]

Download publishsettings file of above created AzureWebsite. Import the publishsettings file to the Visual studio MVC project (right click the project and select publish) as shown below -

[image]

Similarly publish the WebApi project by importing the same publishsettings file. But we need to change the `Destination URL` and `Site name` to the newly created application details. Please check below screenshot –

[image]

Publish both the projects.

Now navigate to http://ramidev1.azurewebsites.net for the MVC site. And navigate to http://ramidev1.azurewebsites.net/webapi/api for WebApi endpoints.

Comment: https://ramidev1.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole would show you the folder structure. NOTE that the webapi folder will not be created until after you publish

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that with virtual directory.

Quote from [Add virtual directory to existing website on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115290/add-virtual-directory-to-existing-website-on-azure)

> Virtual Directories are supported for Azure Websites. See Configuring
>   Azure Websites for what you can do through the Azure Management
>   Portal. From the Azure Portal, click on the Website and go to
>   Configure, then scroll down to virtual applications and directories
>   (the last config section). Just enter your virtual directory and the
>   physical path relative to the site root and click Save.