# Continuous Integration and Automatic Deployment in Azure

Tags: azure

I have more than one web api projects in a single solution file, but when I configure it for continuous integration and automatic deployment it has to be against each project to different web site.

I have created a publish file and provided those details in the MS Builds Build definition file, still it's not taking the specific project to the correct web site.

Comment: Can you check this solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688681/azure-web-app-multiple-apps-hosting/34691297#34691297. let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to specify a particular folder from a github etc deployment you can set an environment variable (App Setting) of Project. so if you have a WebAPI1 and WebAPI2 folder, you can create an APP setting

```
Project = WebAPI1
```

This will make kudu deploy the correct project.

See the kudu documentation for more information - [Customizing deployments](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments)

Comment: can you explain me how to define the build definitions especially how to map the solution file and project files.