# Azure: App Service: Deploy Virtual Directory

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, virtual-directory, azureportal

I have an asp.net core app deployed on azure website and the domain is www.somewebsite.org. My web.config file is under site\wwwroot\web.config. Its contents are

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\App1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
            <environmentVariables>
            </environmentVariables>
        </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am trying to deploy another asp.net core app with the virtual path www.somewebsite.org/kiosk and I copied the complete directory under site\wwwroot\kiosk and the web.config file is under site\wwwroot\kiosk\web.config. Its contents are:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>            
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />      
    </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Kiosk.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

On Azure portal, in Application Settings for my site, I have
/      -  site\wwwroot
/kiosk -  site\wwwroot\kiosk

When I try going to www.somewebsite.org, the app1 site is loaded whis is correct. But, when I go to www.somewebsite.org/kiosk, the kiosk app is not being loaded. The page comes back with a 500 Internal Server Error. How do I fix this error?  Is it even possible to host multiple apps from separate multiple virtual paths under one website in azure?

Comment: Did you try configuring the [virtual directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15122761/7073340) in Azure portal ?

Comment: Yes. It is configured as / - site\wwwroot and /kiosk - site\wwwroot\kiosk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my sub-application web.config file, I did the following and it started working:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>            
        <add name="aspNetCore_TEMP" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />      
    </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Kiosk.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Now, both the sites are up.

Thanks for your help.

NH

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce your error, and you just need to add `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">` in you `web.config` file which is under `site\wwwroot\web.config`.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\App1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
            <environmentVariables>
            </environmentVariables>
        </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried this solution and the website stopped working(App1.dll).